# MySQL Column Text Comparison Search

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that has a category column and a keyword column. The category column can have one of two values: category1 or category2. Records in category1 have multiple words in the keyword column and records in category2 have single words in the keyword column.

I need to find all the records that are in category1 where their keywords contain a keyword from category2 as a whole word.

For example:

```
id  category   keyword

1  category1  word1 word2
2  category1  word2 word3
3  category1  word2 word4
4  category2  word1
5  category2  word3
```

In this example, records 1 and 2 would be retrieved.

I tried the following query:

```
select sn1.category, sn1.keyword 
from keyword_set sn1 
join keyword_set sn2 
on (
sn1.keyword like concat(sn2.keyword, ' %') or 
sn1.keyword like concat('% ', sn2.keyword, ' %') or
sn1.keyword like concat('% ', sn2.keyword)
)
where sn1.category = category1 
and sn2.caegory = category2
```

This works, but it's too slow for a large number of records.

I also tried the  `REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]'` type search and it is also too slow.

I have an index on the keyword column.

Is there any way to do this efficiently?

Comment: Just an idea: make a table/view that contains that contains keywords of cat2. Then you can just use `WHERE EXIST` to check if any cat1 keyword is also in cat2.

Comment: @aakashjain: How would I use WHERE EXIST with that table/view?